# Python: Not multiple print not equal to 0

Tags: python

I am new to Python. How can I know if a function is being used or not; if it is not equal to zero then the program will print; otherwise, do not print any zero.

```
b1 = (int(a1[0]) + int(a2[0])) // 10
b2 = (int(a1[1]) + int(a2[1])) // 10
b3 = (int(a1[2]) + int(a2[2])) // 10

if (b1,b2,b3) !=0:
     print (b1, b2, b3)
```

Comment: What do you mean excactly, do you only want to print if b1, b2 and b3 is not 0 ?

Comment: Depending on whether you want _all_ or _any_ value to be non-zero, you can use either `if b1*b2*b3!=0` or `if b1+b2+b3!=0`.

Comment: @DYZ Much more readable to use `(b1,b2,b3) != (0,0,0)` (or with `==`). If the condition is "any" instead of "all" you can do `0 in (b1,b2,b3)` or `0 not in (b1,b2,b3)`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta You can do it in _many_ different ways.

Comment: @DYZ Yes, but `b1*b2*b3` is specific to numbers and `b1+b2+b3` is specific to *non negative* numbers. If the OP finds a similar situation where instead of `0` you have, say, the empty string, your proposed solution becomes 100% useless, the tuple version works exactly the same and hence is useful in a wider range of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

In Python, `(b1,b2,b3)` represents a `tuple` object. And it is obviously not equal to the int object zero, so your if condition is always satisfied.

You can change your code to this if you want to print when any of the three is not zero:

```
if b1 != 0 or b2 != 0 or b3 != 0:
    print(b1,b2,b3)
```

Comment: "if it is not equal to zero then the program will print; otherwise, do not print any zero." As per her question it seems condition will be ``b1 != 0 and b2 != 0 and b3 != 0``

Comment: @vanneilsen Thanks for pointing out. The question is indeed a bit confusing. I'm just showing a possible way to correct the error in the if condition. If the OP edits the question I'll change my answer.

Comment: Yes I agree...You explained pretty well in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As it's array instead of checking values like that you can even use loop

```
for i in range(3):
    if int(a1[i]) + int(a2[i]) != 0:
        print(int(a1[i]) + int(a2[i]))
```

This will print only the answers which are not equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can store all the elements b1,b2,b3 in the list and check the specific values:

```
a1=[0,2,3]
a2=[0,0,4]
b1 = int(a1[0]) + int(a2[0])
b2 = int(a1[1]) + int(a2[1])
b3 = int(a1[2]) + int(a2[2]) 
temp=[b1,b2,b3]
if 0 in temp:
  print(b1, b2, b3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple instead of the int list:

Here's it is how you can use:

```
thistuple = (0,2,3,1)
for i in range(len(thistuple)):
    if(thistuple[i] != 0):
        print (thistuple[i])
```